# Expert system VS OWL/RDF ontology

Tags: jena, semantic-web, owl, ontology, expert-system

To build a rule-based expert system, what tools should be chosen? These two seems to be old tools for building expert system:

```
* Clip: http://www.clipsrules.net/
* Jess in Java
```

Are these three below also for the purpose of building expert system, as above two?

```
* Manchester OWL
* Protege OWL
* Jena API
```

It seems like the traditional 'expert system' has been outdated, and they are replaced by semantic web/ontology technologies. Can I say OWL and Jena API can achieve same things as a traditional expert system?

Comment: CLIPS probably has more in common with [logic programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924654/datalog-vs-clips-vs-prolog/5616371) languages than with OWL, since its rules can be expressed as first-order logic predicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

OWL is a knowledge representation language (and a set of applicable inference rules) - it is a W3C standard available here: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-overview/

Jena API supports RDF (which is another W3C standard, with strong relations to OWL) and OWL 1 (the current OWL version is 2); it also supports non standard extensions through a rule reasoner. It could be used to implement an expert system, but it is not, per se, a replacement for Jess or CLIPS.

Side note: Manchester OWL and Protege OWL don't really exist. Protege is a tool for creating OWL ontologies, supporting a number of OWL serialization formats (RDF/XML, OWL/XML, Turtle, Manchester syntax, Functional syntax, and more); Protege OWL is a plugin for an older Protege version - current Protege (5.1) has no 'OWL plugin' - OWL is integrated in the tool itself.
Manchester OWL is sometimes used to refer to Manchester syntax for OWL - this is nothing but a name for the format, and does not indicate any difference in expressivity.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that "Expert Systems" of old have been absorbed into different applications/contexts - the actual mechanics (forward chaining, backward chaining, [Rete Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm), etc) are just being repurposed.

A [Semantic Reasoner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_reasoner) is an expert system where the inference rules are expressed in terms of an ontology.  [Pellet](https://github.com/stardog-union/pellet) is a semantic reasoner for Jena.

Another area is BPMN and [business rules engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine) where, if we ignore the "workflow" component, we're left with a recognizable Expert System.

So you can use Jena as the basis for an Expert System - as per @Ignazio's answer, but it really depends on what you're trying to solve.  A rich ontology has value in and of itself, you can do query-by-example (intersection), but the generation/curation costs of such a representation may be prohibitive.